# Angular 4 after reloading redirect me to base href instead of staying at the same page

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, refresh, reload

I have created an `Angular 4` app with `routing, canAccess, AuthGuard`. So ex. I am on page: `http://localhost:4200/#/items` and routing on diffrent pages looks great. But when I reload/refresh page in browser it automatically redirect me to `http://localhost:4200/#/`. I tried something with `APP_BASE_HREF` in `providers` or keeping current href in `localStorage` but none of this work at all. Does anyone have any clue?

Below I post kind of configuration which might help you:

```
<base href="/">

  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'items', component: ItemListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    ])
  ],

      providers: [
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor, multi: true},
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
        AuthenticationService,
        AuthGuard,
      ],
```

Comment: Try `{path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},`

Comment: Does your server support HTML5 pushstate?

Comment: Nope, doesnt work

Comment: On the server side is `Spring Boot`

Comment: I had the same issue when i had a node.js project in the root of the app and the angular project as a subdirectory (view). Is that the case for you (but with java)?

Comment: Yes at the Server side is java.